# Can't get Penn Foster to work on anything but Chrome, want to use on Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, website

I want it to work on Firefox or even CHROMIUM, but whenever I try to read an article for school, it refreshes over and over until it logs me out. It shows me the article in between refreshes. Is there some sort of workaround for this, like tricking the website into thinking I'm on Chrome, or is it a bug I can fix? It's on Linux, not Windows.

Comment: Question can be closed because it is no longer reproducable and does not contain any useful in formation for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

As expected **https://www.pennfoster.edu/** is written for IE Edge browser which would explain why you have issues on FireFox:

[image: 0]

As for a workaround you asking for you can use sandboxed browsers like for example:

- **https://www.browserling.com/**
- **https://turbo.net/browsers**

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but thanks.